# Python throwing error: Expected bytes, got a 'dict' object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I am trying to fetch result from Google URL inspection API and save it into Google BigQuery Table. Everything on URL inspection API and BigQuery is good. I know because I am using other APIs and saving data into bigQuery.

But I have this python script which throws error when executed. Following is the Error. It looks like error is dict object but because I am new in python therefore could not figure out where is the error exactly. Please! can anybody help me out?

Also if possible can you suggest best solution I am trying to achieve.
Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\gsconsole_online\urlinspection1\u_inspect_module.py", line 105, in <module>
    load_job = bigQueryClient.load_table_from_dataframe(result, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.py", line 2628, in load_table_from_dataframe
    _pandas_helpers.dataframe_to_parquet(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_pandas_helpers.py", line 672, in dataframe_to_parquet
    arrow_table = dataframe_to_arrow(dataframe, bq_schema)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_pandas_helpers.py", line 617, in dataframe_to_arrow
    bq_to_arrow_array(get_column_or_index(dataframe, bq_field.name), bq_field)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_pandas_helpers.py", line 342, in bq_to_arrow_array
    return pyarrow.Array.from_pandas(series, type=arrow_type)
  File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 1033, in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas
  File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 312, in pyarrow.lib.array
  File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 83, in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 123, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'dict' object
```

Here is the python script.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound
import pandas as pd

indexScopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'
    ]

indexCredentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("credentials.json", scopes=indexScopes)
indexService = build('searchconsole','v1',credentials=indexCredentials)

indexRequest = {
    'inspectionUrl': 'https://example.com/',
    'siteUrl': 'https://example.com/'
}

response = indexService.urlInspection().index().inspect(body=indexRequest).execute()
inspectionResult = response['inspectionResult']

full_table_name = "bigquery-project.dataset.table"

from time import gmtime, strftime
current_datetime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

result = {"site": [], "json_response": [], "created_at":[], "updated_at":[]}

result["site"].append('https://example.com/')
result["json_response"].append(inspectionResult)
result["created_at"].append(str(current_datetime))
result["updated_at"].append(str(current_datetime))

result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result)

bigQueryScopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery']
bigQuerycredentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("bigquery-consonle.json", scopes=bigQueryScopes)

bigQueryClient = bigquery.Client(credentials=bigQuerycredentials)

try:
    table_ref = bigQueryClient.get_table(full_table_name)  # Make an API request.
except NotFound:
    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("site", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("json_response", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("created_at", "DATETIME"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("updated_at", "DATETIME"),
    ]

    table     = bigquery.Table(full_table_name, schema=schema)
    table     = bigQueryClient.create_table(table)
    table_ref = bigQueryClient.get_table(full_table_name)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("site", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("json_response", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("created_at", "DATETIME"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("updated_at", "DATETIME"),
    ], autodetect=False)

#job_config.destination = table_ref
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'

load_job = bigQueryClient.load_table_from_dataframe(result, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
load_job.result()
```

Comment: Anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

`insertionResult` appended in the `json_response` of the `result` dataframe is a `dict` whereas it's declared in the schema as a string.

Serialize `insertionResult` to a JSON encoded string.

```py
import json

inspectionResult = json.dumps(response['inspectionResult'])
```